# ActiveMQ consumer in AKS

Tags: activemq-classic, azure-aks

I have an ActiveMQ consumer in AKS I am trying to connect to a external service.

I have setup a AKS load balancer with a dedicated IP with with the following rules but it will not connect.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mx-load-balancer
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 1.1.1.1
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
  - name: activemq-port-61616
    port: 61616
    targetPort: 61616
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    k8s-app: handlers-mx
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your loadBalancerIP is not a real one, you need to use a real IP of your LB. Second,  you need to add annotation for service of type `LoadBalancer` to [work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address):

```
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: LB_RESORCE_GROUP
```